# Spring : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT in Clusterd Tomcat failover

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

We have a clusterd tomcat environment with two nodes(trunk-n1 and trunk-n2) each node has apache and tomcat instances, we are having issue in the below scenario

Load balancer URL is `https://trunk/PP` which is pointed to `trunk-n1` and `trunk-n2` nodes, When both nodes are up and user logs into the application  load balancer assign one of the nodes(lets say N1) if the user is on N1 and when we bring the N1 node down user should be redirected to N2 seamlessly but sometimes user getting logged out

Below are the request headers and spring security debug logs for seamless redirection for the above scenario

```
Headers when user is on N1
    Request Headers:
        GET /PP/core/images/icons/cross.png HTTP/1.1
        Host: trunk:443
        Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
        Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
        Cookie: sessionIdForCognos=ADB5D9EC2AF7FC0B04795E066C429E97.trunk-n1
        Referer: https://trunk/PP/core/css/icons.css
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
    Response Headers:
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Accept-Ranges: bytes
        Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Length: 655
        Content-Type: image/png
        Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 17:31:19 GMT
        ETag: "28f-5234b6e15e000"
        Expires: Sat, 04 Apr 2026 17:31:19 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=70, max=97
        Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 05:09:20 GMT
        Server: None
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
        X-UA-Compatible: IE=9

Headers when N1 took and redirected to N2
    Request Headers:
        GET /PP/timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 HTTP/1.1
        Host: trunk:443
        Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
        Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
        Cache-Control: no-cache
        Cookie: WebDAV.activeX=false; JSESSIONID=ADB5D9EC2AF7FC0B04795E066C429E97.trunk-n1; sessionIdForCognos=ADB5D9EC2AF7FC0B04795E066C429E97.trunk-n1
        Referer: https://trunk/PP/enduser/listscreens/show.do?screenName=Lawfirm%20Invoice%20Parcels
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
        X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Response Headers:
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Encoding: gzip
        Content-Length: 74
        Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
        Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 17:32:01 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=70, max=95
        Server: None
        Set-Cookie: sessionIdForCognos=ADB5D9EC2AF7FC0B04795E066C429E97.trunk-n2; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
        Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ADB5D9EC2AF7FC0B04795E066C429E97.trunk-n2; Path=/PP; Secure; HttpOnly
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
        X-UA-Compatible: IE=9

App log from N2
------------------------
[Apr 06 17:31:52,233] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | kJWPdVD9IUVz | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[Apr 06 17:32:02,175] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,177] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | kJWPdVD9IUVz | Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@9caf2e44: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@9caf2e44: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@536a6fad: Username: user1@dc.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 1.1.1.1; SessionId: CB186F4366D029B81933B16BD7E4F9A4.trunk-n1; Not granted any authorities'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,201] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WelcomePageRedirectFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,201] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,201] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'InternalAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,202] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,202] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,203] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,203] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,203] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,203] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,203] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@9caf2e44: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@536a6fad: Username: user1@dc.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 1.1.1.1; SessionId: CB186F4366D029B81933B16BD7E4F9A4.trunk-n1; Not granted any authorities'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,204] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,204] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[Apr 06 17:32:02,204] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | user1@dc.com | kJWPdVD9IUVz | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459963879470 at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
```

Failed user redirection with logout

```
Headers when user is on N2
    Request Headers:
        GET /PP/core/images/icons/pencil.png HTTP/1.1
        Host: trunk:443
        Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
        Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
        Cookie: sessionIdForCognos=46A37357A369A1065184EDDA3AE0ED0C.trunk-n2
        Referer: https://trunk/PP/core/css/icons.css
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
    Response Headers:
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Accept-Ranges: bytes
        Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Length: 450
        Content-Type: image/png
        Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:26:12 GMT
        ETag: "1c2-5234b6e15e000"
        Expires: Sat, 04 Apr 2026 16:26:12 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=70, max=86
        Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 05:09:20 GMT
        Server: None
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
        X-UA-Compatible: IE=9

Headers when N2 is down and redirected to N1
    Request Headers:
        GET /PP/j_spring_security_logout?ajax=true&_=1459959972331 HTTP/1.1
        Host: trunk:443
        Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
        Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
        Cache-Control: no-cache
        Cookie: WebDAV.activeX=false; JSESSIONID=46A37357A369A1065184EDDA3AE0ED0C.trunk-n2; sessionIdForCognos=46A37357A369A1065184EDDA3AE0ED0C.trunk-n2
        Referer: https://trunk/PP/enduser/listscreens/show.do?screenName=Lawfirm%20Invoice%20Parcels
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
        X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Response Headers:
        HTTP/1.1 302 Found
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Length: 0
        Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:27:29 GMT
        Keep-Alive: timeout=70, max=83
        Location: https://trunk/PP/index.do
        Server: None
        Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DAD957102283938AA31F157085F9818D.trunk-n1; Path=/PP; Secure; HttpOnly
        Set-Cookie: sessionIdForCognos=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
        X-UA-Compatible: IE=9


App log
-----------------------
[Apr 06 16:27:22,305] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | BKrUPVga5kki | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[Apr 06 16:27:29,740] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,741] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  |  | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
[Apr 06 16:27:29,741] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  |  | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@773b75c1. A new one will be created.
[Apr 06 16:27:29,742] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WelcomePageRedirectFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,742] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,742] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'InternalAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,742] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,742] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,742] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,743] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,743] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,743] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,743] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter | anonymousUser |  | Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90541710: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 1.1.1.1; SessionId: 46A37357A369A1065184EDDA3AE0ED0C.trunk-n1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,743] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,743] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/admin/**'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/system/upgrade.do'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/system/upgradestatus.do'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/enduser/ajax/upgradecounts.do'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/system/**'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/enduser/**'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,744] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/changepassword.do'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,745] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher | anonymousUser |  | Checking match of request : '/timeout.do'; against '/index.do'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,745] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor | anonymousUser |  | Public object - authentication not attempted
[Apr 06 16:27:29,746] INFO  | org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener | anonymousUser |  | Security interception not required for public secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330
[Apr 06 16:27:29,746] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser |  | /timeout.do?ajax=true&_=1459959972330 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[Apr 06 16:27:29,751] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter | anonymousUser | uDCzcUTsm7SD | Chain processed normally
[Apr 06 16:27:29,751] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | uDCzcUTsm7SD | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[Apr 06 16:27:29,751] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | uDCzcUTsm7SD | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[Apr 06 16:27:29,767] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | BKrUPVga5kki | /j_spring_security_logout?ajax=true&_=1459959972331 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,768] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | BKrUPVga5kki | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
[Apr 06 16:27:29,768] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | BKrUPVga5kki | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@773b75c1. A new one will be created.
[Apr 06 16:27:29,768] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | BKrUPVga5kki | /j_spring_security_logout?ajax=true&_=1459959972331 at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WelcomePageRedirectFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,768] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | BKrUPVga5kki | /j_spring_security_logout?ajax=true&_=1459959972331 at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,768] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | BKrUPVga5kki | /j_spring_security_logout?ajax=true&_=1459959972331 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'InternalAuthenticationFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,769] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | BKrUPVga5kki | /j_spring_security_logout?ajax=true&_=1459959972331 at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,769] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter |  | BKrUPVga5kki | Logging out user 'null' and transferring to logout destination
[Apr 06 16:27:29,769] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler |  | BKrUPVga5kki | Invalidating session: 46A37357A369A1065184EDDA3AE0ED0C.trunk-n1
[Apr 06 16:27:29,778] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy |  | BKrUPVga5kki | Redirecting to '/PP/index.do'
[Apr 06 16:27:29,778] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | BKrUPVga5kki | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[Apr 06 16:27:29,779] DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | BKrUPVga5kki | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Can someone help me fixing this random user logout issue when one of the node is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat session was not replicated and causing the user to logout when one of the node goes down, configured `hazelcast` to achieve session replication as below

**Step 1: Add below dependencies to pom.xml**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-wm</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Step 2: Add below snippet on top of the existing filters in `web.xml` so that request first goes to `hazelcast`**

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>hazelcast-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter</filter-class>
    <!--
        Name of the distributed map storing
        your web session objects
    -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>map-name</param-name>
        <param-value>my-sessions</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/hazelcast.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sticky-session</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Are you debugging? Default is false.-->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hazelcast-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.hazelcast.web.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Step 3: Create `hazelcast.xml` as below**

```xml
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</hazelcast>
```

**Step 4: Initialize `sessionRegistry` bean in your `applicationContext.xml`**

```xml
<bean id="sessionRegistry" 
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Restart your application and session replication works on tomcat failover

Doc Reference:
http://hazelcast.org/use-cases/clustering/
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/websessionreplication.html
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#preface

Configuration reference:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-security