# Tomcat 7 Session replication issue on fail-over

Tags: java, session, tomcat, hazelcast

We recently clustered our application with 2 tomcat nodes(7.0.53) and the cluster was setup as per the Tomcat documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Everything works as expected except the session replication doesnt work on fail over, I had to setup `hazelcast` on both tomcat instances to make the session replication work. I refered to `hazelcast` documentation to setup http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/websessionreplication.html and session replication works perfectly on tomcat failure. I am just wondering is this a bug with Tomcat session replication? Or is it mandatory to use 3rd party libraries like `hazelcast` to achieve session replication on tomcat failure?

Comment: Happy to hear you were successful using Hazelcast, anyhow I cannot help you on your initial question regarding Tomcat Session Replication as I never tried to use it. If you decide to go along with Hazelcast in the end, I'm glad to jump in for questions though :)

Comment: @noctarius I do have few questions. I've configured the hazelcast like this, please check my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463054/spring-httpsession-returned-null-object-for-spring-security-context-in-cluster as per the documentation on your website I understood that hazelcast creates the session and maintains but how does both hazelcast instances communicate to replicate the session accross multiple hazelcast instances? Does it use McastService IP address configured on tomcat or via any other channels?

Comment: Second question initialy I configured `com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter` as `hazelcast-filter` and it worked on failover but our application uses spring security so later I configured `com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter` Are there any implications of using `WebFilter` instead of `SpringAwareWebFilter`?

Comment: Third question, after configuring the `hazelcast` i see tomcat's `JSESSIONID` and `hazelcast.sessionId` in response headers I assume `hazelcast.sessionId` will be the used through out all the web transactions, but how does spring aware of using the `hazelcast.sessionId` for authentication instead of `JSESSIONID`?

Comment: I think you already put your questions into Google Group and it seems Mesut answered them. Please let me know if there is anything else I can help with. Sorry for the late answer though.